# Not able to access secured back end service through WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

My requirement is to call a secured backend service through WSO2 EI 6, 
So i tried to add the Property mediator and header mediator as below, but I am not able to access the secured API.

`<header name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="Bearer 1e127891-c430-3312-87ab-a2ba23ef8a4d"/>`

The whole API looks like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/nexgen" name="ChainApis" publishSwagger="nexgen" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/getProviders">
        <inSequence>
            <header name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="Bearer 1e127891-c430-3312-87ab-a2ba23ef8a4d"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="LdapTest"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log>
                <property name="checklist" value="after call"/>
            </log>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

And the Endpoint looks like below.

```
<endpoint name="LdapTest" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <http method="get" uri-template="https://******/***/1.0/getLdapUserData?userName=suresh">
        <suspendOnFailure>
            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
            <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
        </suspendOnFailure>
        <markForSuspension>
            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
        </markForSuspension>
    </http>

</endpoint>

I even tried with the below property mediator too 
<property expression="fn:concat('Bearer ', 'db9df6c0-dfd4-3fde-ba0f-b9a524f0c9b0')" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>


the below is the log i get in my log file.
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-02-07 14:35:56,703]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  
    To: /nexgen/getProviders, MessageID: urn:uuid:c0409753-deb4-4c28-8d1e-23db599b4296, 
    Direction: request, Envelope: 
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body/>
    </soapenv:Envelope> 
    {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

Comment: are you able to call the api directly?

Comment: Yes, I am able to call the API directly and get the result.

Comment: Could you please enable http wire logs in EI and check whether the correct request is sent to the backend with the header?

Comment: Yes i have enabled the wirelogs and getting the below logs only. TID: [-1234] [] [2020-02-10 14:14:41,333]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /nexgen1/getProviders, MessageID: urn:uuid:8ad16392-f40a-4b42-ac45-fa3d3a641cc5, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}